# How to get the full generated code of a module using Elixir macros

Tags: compilation, metaprogramming, elixir, phoenix-framework

Below is the router module for a sample Phoenix application. I would like to see the full code of the module *after* macros inject functions.

I tried things like `Macro.to_string (Macro.expand (Code.string_to_quoted! File.read!("web/router.ex")), __ENV__)` but it doesn't fully expand the macros. How could I recursively expand every macro, i.e. `pipeline`, `plug`, `scope`, `pipe_through` and `get`.

Thanks

```
defmodule HelloPhoenix.Router do
  use HelloPhoenix.Web, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/", HelloPhoenix do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    get "/", PageController, :index
  end

end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This bit of code will decompile a beam file back to erlang.  I haven't run it against a plug-based module, so I don't know how nasty the result will be, but this gives you the final result for *any* module.

```
  def disassemble(beam_file) do
    beam_file = String.to_char_list(beam_file)
    {:ok,
      {_, [{:abstract_code, {_, ac}}]}} = :beam_lib.chunks(beam_file,
                                                           [:abstract_code])
    :io.fwrite('~s~n', [:erl_prettypr.format(:erl_syntax.form_list(ac))])
  end
```

original source, and more info: http://erlang.org/doc/man/beam_lib.html

Note that this method takes the **file path** of [module].beam

Comment: Too bad we can't have elixir code but as I can read erlang better than elixir it's okay for me :) Thank you

Answer (score 6):

As you have correctly observed, you need to use `Macro.expand/1` recursively to truly expand *all* macro levels. There is a built-in facility to achieve this: `Macro.prewalk/2`. This should get you started:

```
ast
|> Macro.prewalk(&Macro.expand(&1, __ENV__))
|> Macro.to_string
|> IO.puts
```

Comment: I can't make it work. I also found a package called Mex that can't seem to print the full code either. But thanks anyway, I'll tinker a bit more

Comment: Oh it seems inspecting modules is not as straightforward, sorry. If you want to get a quick and dirty solution you can try to manually inject the inspection code into the module itself, so that your `__ENV__` is within the module. Can't check right now but you might have some success with that.